# RegEx l33t speak recognizer?

Tags: javascript, html, regex, user-input

I know questions *similar* to this have been asked but this is more specific.

I have a site that takes user input, but needs to filter out some words. For example, lets use the word example. The 3 can be substituted for e and 4 for a, and I can easily build something to catch that on a case by case basis [Seen Here](https://regexr.com/5gd0j), but I have no idea how to do that with a database of words.

I have a txt file that contains a list of no-no words, and can get it to filter them, but if somebody types 3x4mpl3, then that will get excepted.

The code for the filter is :

```
async function isinapropriate(text) {
    const fileStream = fs.createReadStream(__dirname + "/disabledwords.txt");
    const rl = readline.createInterface({
      input: fileStream,
      crlfDelay: Infinity
    });
    for await (const line of rl) {
      if (
        new RegExp("(^| )" + line + "($| )", "g").test(
          text
            .split(": ")
            .slice(1)
            .join(": ")
        )
      ) {
        console.log(text);
        console.log("Word: " + line);
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
```

How can I get it so that it recognizes ex4mple as example?

Also, it case sensitive so if example is in the database, eXaMpLe would still work. Is there a way to fix *that*? Also one last problem (sorry), e x a m p l e also works, and I know the solution involves `\s` or something, but I cannot get a way to fix it.

### Edit

The application I am writing is a forum/chatroom app. The only user input is what they post

Comment: Censorship is something that will always be something you can step around in some shape or form, 455 could be ass but it could also be 455. I wouldn't put much faith in anything that's not a static list of banned words

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of trying to create a regex for every word in the whitelist, first normalize the input word:

```js
function normalize(inp) {
    const leet = {
        "1": "l",
        "3": "e",
        "4": "a",
        "5": "s",
        "7": "t",
        "0": "o"
    };
    // get rid of leetspeak
    for (let num in leet) {
        inp = inp.replaceAll(num, leet[num]);
    }
    // get rid of casing
    inp = inp.toLowerCase();
    // get rid of non-alphanumeric characters
    inp = inp.replace(/\W/g, "");
    return inp;
}

// all "example"
normalize("3x4mpl3");
normalize("e x a m p l e");
normalize("ExaMplE");
```

Comment: You can add `"@": "a"` to the replacement list. You can't cover every case without nlp or something of the like, so you have to choose between overcorrecting or undercorrecting.

Comment: johnadoe.com - my point is, these things aren't perfect, or reliable, but heres some rep++

Comment: Here's one: `I have an appointment at 4:55` -> `I have an appointment at a:ss` lol

Comment: @Aplet123 Forgive my probably dumb question, as I am extremely terrible at both regex and js, but is there an easy way to save the original, so if the original post is deemed fine, you can revert to the old post? I guess variables would work, but I am really not sure

Comment: You could just save it in a variable somewhere.